# What are some best practices to include test coverage in an Angularjs project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, unit-testing, tdd

I am working on angularjs + rails project, we have to include test coverage in the project, so for rails (i.e. backend) Rspec has been used, but for angularjs (i.e. front end) test coverage tool needs to be introduced, so can anyone suggest which tool can be used to do unit testing on front-end part?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Both the answers below are correct. Protractor will be for your End-to-End testing and you would then use Karma for your Unit Testing. We actually use Rails as our backend here and use Capybara for End-to-End testing as opposed to Protractor - simply because 2 developers know how to use Capybara and only one (myself) knows how to use Protractor

Comment: Test coverage and unit-testing are two different things. You can run unit-tests with Karma as the test-framework and Jasmine as the test-suite. Code coverage means how much of the code you've written is covered by unit tests. Code coverage reports can automatically be created by using a tool like Istanbul (https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul).

Answer (score 0):

The most common one I can think of is [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/)

Comment: Thanks for the replies!!... I would like to go further with Jasmine, along with Karma or Teaspoon, not with Protractor, as we need to use TDD approach for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) via [Teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon).
Teaspoon is a test runner which easily sets up your testing environment and allows you to run your tests easily.

[This book](http://angular-rails.com/) is a great source in general, and more specifially, [here the chapter about testing](http://angular-rails.com/find_and_browse.html#tests) where it describes how to set up and use Teaspoon.